# Am using drf-spectacular for my Django rest api documentation, how to override our own endpoint

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger

In below code am not able to generate schema for 2 endpoints admin/ and   payslip/

> ```
> urlpatterns = [
> # YOUR PATTERNS
> path('admin/', admin.site.urls),,
> path('payslip/',include('payslip.urls'))
> path('api/schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name='schema'),
> # Optional UI:
> path('api/schema/swagger-ui/', SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name='schema'), name='swagger-ui'),
> path('api/schema/redoc/', SpectacularRedocView.as_view(url_name='schema'), name='redoc'), ]
> ```

Comment: Is your syntax correct ? from: `path('admin/', admin.site.urls),,` to: `path('admin/', admin.site.urls),` ... I saw an extra comma. Not sure if is relevant to your question. Is helpful to explain the swagger command/integration you have, how you generate and what error you get.

Answer (score 1):

The Django admin is not built from REST API endpoints. The admin is made of a lot of regular Django templated html views. Views discovered by `drf-spectacular` must be derived from either `APIView` or `GenericAPIView` in one way or another. These are the fundamental base classes of `rest_framework`.

Can't really attest to what `payslip` is made of but the same rules apply there.